# How do I actually get Lua to work?

Tags: lua, installation

I'm doing a game development course and we are playing around with the Love2D game engine. I'm quite new to programming and I'd like to learn some more Lua before going further but I'm having a hard time actually getting Lua to work at all. What I mean by that is the whole installing and downloading part seems to be quite different from other languages I've played around with in the past.

With Python for example you just download the interpreter and whatnot and you're good to go.

I've downloaded Lua for Windows. https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/

It installs Lua and a text editor called SciTE. However I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm using sublime text editor and saving my programs as example.lua but I can't seem to get the programs to run.

Would anybody more enlightened in the ways of lua care to help a beginner out?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Are your programs not running at all, or just not working right?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. When I run the program it just opens the small black lua console for a mili second and then closes.

Comment: Open a command line and run it from there. The program is running and exiting very quickly (either because an error occurred or because it just completes quickly) and windows doesn't keep the output window around for you to look at. If luaforwindows is properly installed you should just be able to type "lua path/to/file.lua" at the prompt to run it.

Comment: thanks, and how do I run a program from the lua window?

Comment: If you're in the Lua interactive interpreter (by entering `lua` at a command line) you can do `dofile 'example.lua'`. If you're just at a command line you can run `lua example.lua`.

Answer (score 3):

Lua for Windows is still a good place to start with Lua on Windows, but it does have some limitations to be aware of for the future. The most visible is that it installs Lua 5.1 and not Lua 5.2. In the Lua universe, version numbers of the base language change very slowly, and there are some large changes in the language from 5.1 to 5.2. That said, one of the best free resources about the language is the online first edition of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html), which describes version 5.0 and is still *mostly* relevant even to 5.2 programming. If you are serious about learning Lua well, you will want to buy the current (third) edition of PiL from a bookseller "near" you.

I believe that as of the current release (v0.8.0) [Löve2D](https://love2d.org/) is still based on Lua 5.1, however, so the version provided in Lua for Windows is a good match.

LfW will install the basic Lua interpreter in two forms: `lua.exe` and `wlua.exe`. It will put both on your `PATH`. It also installed the SciTE editor which has built-in support for debugging Lua and can be scripted and extended in Lua as well. But you don't have to use SciTE, any text editor will do.

For Löve, you might actually prefer to get [Zero Brane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) which is a full Lua IDE that knows about the Löve engine and not only can debug games directly, but can even be used for live coding where you can edit many aspects of the game while it is running with the changes taking effect immediately.

To get a simple hello world example going with a fresh install of Lua for Windows, use your favorite text editor to create `hello.lua` with something like the following:

```
print("hello from " .. _VERSION)
```

From a command prompt in the folder where you saved `hello.lua`, type `hello.lua` to run it:

```
C:\Users\Ross\Documents\tmp\SOQuestions>hello.lua
hello from Lua 5.1

C:\Users\Ross\Documents\tmp\SOQuestions>
```

Like Python and Perl, the basic Lua interpreter is a command line program. It can be extended through add-on libraries (called "modules" in Lua jargon) to add the ability to create full GUI applications, or the core language interpreter can be embedded in a GUI application framework as is done with Löve. `Lua.exe` is the pure command-line version, and as such it requires that a console window exist to provide a place for its standard input and output to be connected. `Wlua.exe` is a similarly basic interpreter, but has been built for Windows in a way that does not require or use a console window; it is intended for programs that use one of several GUI framework modules to implement a more normal Windows GUI application.

To get started with the Lua language, working through the first few chapters of Programming in Lua using `lua.exe` at the command prompt and the editor of your choice will provide a very solid background in how to use the language.

Since you are intended to use the Löve engine, also working through their tutorials will be helpful. But I strongly suspect that learning the basics of Lua syntax first will make those tutorials a lot easier to follow.